# Should I create C# form at runtime

Tags: c#, forms, runtime

I have a form, from which the professor can go to another form and upload the pdf of a lesson or a test so the students can read the lesson or take the test. Is it faster to create this second form(which I am using for the file's upload) at runtime or add it at the solution explorer beforehand?
Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT #1**

I wanted to learn, from someone who had already tested it, if there is any difference in speed between the creation of a form in the runtime and the creation of a form beforehand. I tried to fing the answer to it, online, before posting this question here but i didn't get any luck.

Comment: The usual reply [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Without having a FORM already designed how can you run it? that's weird

Comment: "Create" using VS designer, but "Show" it using code in runtime.

Comment: @Rahul He can create a Form object and add controls at run-time.

Comment: @user3185569, don't you think that itself is weird?

Comment: @Rahul Well in Xamarin for example, most of the tutorials build the design at run-time by adding objects and nodes and not through XAML. It is weird, but it is a valid approach. Some can argue that is is easier than XAML. As for windows forms, I find it disturbing.

Comment: @user3185569, Ahh!!! there you are ... since OP is talking about Winform and till date I haven't seen any one building a form scratch @ runtime ... so weird.

Comment: @Steve I asked 'cause I wanted to know if someone has already done the comparison and could inform me about his decision on the matter. I, only, wanted an advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO and experience in this, create it at design time which is better and faster development. Instead of adding controls through c# code and subscribing to events.

If you wan to create it at run-time, you'll have to stick to the Form type `(var form = new Form())` then use `form.Load += something`. So it is as if you're creating an inner class inside the class that is launching this form. **Not to mention the pain of running your app in order to see the design.**

If you create it at design time, it is more clear. You can pass things through the constructor and has clear dependencies.

I used to create a Form at run-time and add controls to it. But that was limited to cases where i need to display only or have a single docked control inside of it. In general, I do that when the logic of the form is very simple and the design is so trivial that i'm not interested in creating a separate class for it But even in that case, i still find the design-time approach better.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I meant faster to develop and design. Sorry it was not clear.